# Django: form without submit button causes 404 error

Tags: javascript, python, django

I'm creating a project using Django, which includes a form without a submit button. I'm not familiar with js at all so I looked up how to do it. Some answers say I should do it like this

```
<script>
  document.getElementById("search-form").submit();
</script>
```

but in this way, the form is automatically submitted right after I entered this page and caused 404 error.

My html,

```
<form action="GET" action="{% url 'blog:search_entry' %}" id="search-form">
  <input type="text" name="q" placeholder="Search for posts...">
</form>
```

`views.py` is like this

```
def search_entry(request):
     query = request.GET.get('q')

    entries = Entry.objects.filter(
        Q(title__icontains=query) |
        Q(description__icontains=query)
    )

    return render(request, 'blog/search_entry.html', {'entries': entries})
```

`urls.py`

```
path('search_entry/', views.search_entry, name='search_entry'),
```

What am I doing wrong? I was successful when I use submit button btw. So there's not problem with `urls.py`

The error says

> Requested URL: .../entry_list/GET?q=

`entry_list` is the page that has this form.

Comment: You said nothing about when you want the form to be submitted. WIll it be filled out and submitted automatically by JS immediately upon page load? When user presses Enter? After each and every interaction the user has with the textbox?

Comment: I mean immediately after I entered the page that has this form.

Comment: Please post the relevant line(s) of your `urls.py`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the page is loaded in the browser it is parsed and when it comes to:

```
<script>
    document.getElementById("search-form").submit();
</script>
```

the JS code is executed. It searches for an element with the id **search-form** in the document and it submits it.

Because this happens immediately after the page is loaded, the user won't even have a chance to interact with the page. I fail to see what's the intention here.

When the JS code submits the form, the page is redirected to `{% url 'blog:search_entry' %}`.

I assume there is no corresponding `url` defined in your `urls.py` and therefore the HTTP status code 404 (NOT FOUND) is returned.

Please reconsider the whole design of your page. Check your `urls.py` to identify the error's source.

Comment: I mean right after I entered the page that has this form '/entry_list'

Answer (score 1):

You need to add search_entry view to your urls.py.

Comment: Yes I am sure added.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want to search something with query ?q=.
If this is the case please use AJAX request, form submission is not good.

> But if this is not the case:
>   Wrap your JavaScript code in a JavaScript function.
>   Now call this function via some event(depends on your requirement) listener like onclick etc.